# DSE SOLR Synonyms max size 1MB

Tags: solr, datastax

Working with DSE 4.8.5 and SOLR, I am trying to add synonmys dictionary files (size 1,5MB, .aff & .dic as requested in SOLR doc). But when I try to upload the file using dse command I get error:

> max size etc. 
>   dsetool write_resource core.tablename name=frdico.dic file=frdico.dic

It seems that DSE get a restriction for performance reason. What is the tip for working with synonyms ? How I load the dico file?

Please advise. 
Regards

Comment: what's the error message?